# Cannot call specific php function using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to call `saveTaskDB` function from php using ajax. It will return as success but the database is not updated. I have tried creating a `'create.php'` with just the `saveTaskDB` function code in it and when I called the file 'directly', it returns as success plus it will update my database. I don't know why I cannot call a specific function in my php and I also want to know how store my php functions to a single php file and call them via AJAX. Thank you for anyone that can help me.

I have my codes like this

tasklogger.js:

```
function saveTask(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url:"../_tasklogger/classes/tasklog.php", //the page containing php script
        data:{  action: 'add', 
                date: $("#date").val(), 
                taskName: $("#taskName").val(),
                taskType: $("#taskType").val(),
                duration: $("#duration").val(),
                startTime: $("#startTime").val(),
                endTime: $("#endTime").val()
            },
        success: function(data){
            goSuccess();
        }   
     });
}
```

tasklog.php

```
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if (isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])){
   $date= $_POST['date'];
   $taskName= $_POST['taskName'];
   $taskType= $_POST['taskType'];
   $duration= $_POST['duration'];
   $startTime= $_POST['startTime'];
   $endTime= $_POST['endTime'];
   saveTaskDB($date, $taskName, $taskType, $duration, $startTime, $endTime);
}

function saveTaskDB($date, $taskName, $taskType, $duration, $startTime, $endTime){  
try{
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tasks (TaskDate,TaskName,TaskType,Duration,StartTime,EndTime) VALUES(:tdate, :tname, :ttype, :dur, :stime, :etime)");
    $stmt->bindParam(":tdate", $date);
    $stmt->bindParam(":tname", $taskName);
    $stmt->bindParam(":ttype", $taskType);
    $stmt->bindParam(":dur", $duration);
    $stmt->bindParam(":stime", $startTime);
    $stmt->bindParam(":etime", $endTime);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo 'alert("success")';
    }else{
        echo 'alert("wrong")';
    }   
}
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

create.php

```
require 'dbconfig.php';

$date= $_POST['date'];
$taskName= $_POST['taskName'];
$taskType= $_POST['taskType'];
$duration= $_POST['duration'];
$startTime= $_POST['startTime'];
$endTime= $_POST['endTime'];

try{
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tasks (TaskDate,TaskName,TaskType,Duration,StartTime,EndTime) VALUES(:tdate, :tname, :ttype, :dur, :stime, :etime)");
    $stmt->bindParam(":tdate", $date);
    $stmt->bindParam(":tname", $taskName);
    $stmt->bindParam(":ttype", $taskType);
    $stmt->bindParam(":dur", $duration);
    $stmt->bindParam(":stime", $startTime);
    $stmt->bindParam(":etime", $endTime);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }   
}
catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: In `taskLogger.js` what is your expectation of passing `dateType: 'dataString'` in the POST ?

Comment: What is `dateType: 'dataString',` ?

Comment: I'm still new to php and ajax. I tried using `dataType: json` as a datatype and passing a valid json inside but it doesn't update my database. As I read forums online I encountered  `dataType: dataString` and magically my query runs calling 'create.php' directly but not tasklog.php

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I tried removing `dataType: 'dataString' ` and it still works when I call 'create.php' directly. But what I would like to do now is call the `saveTaskDB ()` function from tasklog.php.

Comment: You removed it from your question - but at least did you try testing it with `dataType` not `dateType` ?

Comment: sorry again for my mistake, I've tried `dataType` instead of `dateType` but it still doesn't work

Comment: you can't call javascript function in php....they run in different environments at different times. php runs on server long before page is sent to browser where javascript runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how deep this question goes.  You may need to review the relationship between JavaScript and PHP, or basic web service design patterns.  I say this because I do not know what your big picture goals are.  If you want a basic script that triggers functions, there's thousands of ways to do that.

`dataType:` can be `default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)`

Your `create.php` is returning 
`TRUE` and `FALSE`

Your `tasklog.php` is returning JavaScript `alert()`

These are different types.  Your calling script `tasklogger.js` doesn't do anything with the response.

- I HOPE YOU SCRUB YOUR DATA!*

To trigger arbitrary functions in php, you could evaluate some parameter that you specify in the JavaScript request.  Let's call the variable... `action`.

In PHP you can now evaluate for the action...

```
if(empty($_POST['action'])){
return;
}
switch($_POST['action']){
    case "save":
        $some_var = $_POST['somearg'];
        $some_other = $_POST['another_arg'];
        save($some_var, $some_other);
        break;
    case "delete":
       /* .... some code .... */
       break;

    case "update": 
       /* some code ... 
             notice there is no "break" here... and execution continues to the next case.... falls-thru */
    case "create":
          /* some code */
          break;
    default:
         /* do something else */
}
```

Comment: Im sorry for the confusion this is my first post in stackoverflow. Yes, I just want a basic ajax script to call a 'specific' php function. I'm just using `alert()` in `tasklog.php` to see if my code get through there.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Now I can call my saveTaskDB using ajax but now my ajax doesn't trigger my `success: function(data){ }` how can I solve this?